# MySQL Delete duplicates in consecutive rows

Tags: mysql, duplicates, delete-row

Suppose this table:

```
ID ColA ColB
1   7    8
2   7    9
3   7    9
4   5    8
5   6    9
6   6    9
7   5    4
```

The PK is the ID coumn.
Now, I want to delete all duplicates of `ColA` and `ColB` in consecutive rows.

In this example rows 2,3 and 5,6 contain duplicates.
These shall be removed so that the higher ID is remained.

The output should be:

```
ID ColA ColB
1   7    8

3   7    9
4   5    8

6   6    9
7   5    4
```

How can this be done with mySQL?

Thanks,
Juergen

Comment: Sorry man but have you tried or, at least, thought someting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ID
FROM
    MyTable m1
WHERE
    0 < (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            MyTable m2
        WHERE
            m2.ID = m1.ID - 1 AND 
            m2.ColA = m1.ColA AND 
            m2.ColB = m1.ColB)
```

and then you can use a

```
delete from MyTable where ID in ...
```

query. This way it would surely work in any version.

Comment: There is one problem remaining: I tried your first statement with SELECT, but when writing DELETE MyTable m1 ... the parser complains about m1 for some reason(wrong SQL syntax).

Comment: Probably MySQL doesn't support this type of naming for deletes, however, it's better to use the new approach, in the EDIT, because of the problem I've described in the meantime. The new approach doesn't use this kind of naming. In the first step you select the ID's which should be deleted and using the results of your query you can write the delete statement. Question: Is this written directly in MySQL, or you are running your commands from another technology (like Java, C#, C++, PHP)?

Comment: Directly in MySQL; the error I get with your edit approach is the error 1093: You can't specify target table 'MyTable' for update in FROM clause; I'll try the other two recommendations with a temporary table now.

Comment: @Juergen since the fix wasn't explained, you can avoid this error by aliasing the table in the subquery, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/45494/2578505
Ex: change  `FROM TargetTable` to `FROM (SELECT * FROM TargetTable) as TargetTable_Temp`

Comment: This solution is correct only if IDs are in sequential order. If IDs are not in sequential order, you'll have to replace `m2.ID = m1.ID - 1` with something like `m2.ID = <expression that returns adjacent m1.ID >`.

Comment: @Despotovic true. The question indicates sequentiality though.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicates (id int primary key)

INSERT INTO duplicates (id)
    SELECT t1.id
      FROM table t1
      join table t2 on t2.id = t1.id + 1
     WHERE t1.ColA = t2.ColA
       and t1.ColB = t2.ColB

-- SELECT * FROM duplicates --> are you happy with that? => delete
DELETE table
  FROM table
  join duplicates on table.id = duplicates.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many records you have, this might not be the most efficient:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM table WHERE colA = m.colA AND colB = m.colB ORDER BY id DESC) AS id, m.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB
      FROM  table) m
```

There might be syntax errors because I usually use mssql, but the idea should be similar.

Comment: There is no top keyword in MySQL, Limit is used instead. Also, you don't delete duplicates. Also, your selection doesn't even select the duplicates (consecutive ID's except the first in the sequence) defined in the question. I'm sorry, but I have to downvote you.

Comment: whoops, I missed the delete portion. Misread it, and yes, I should have used LIMIT instead of TOP; that was my ms stuff kicking in. But if you DELETE tabe WHERE NOT IN (above query), you'd be left with the the ids that are not in the nested select, and the nested select selects the first highest id because I order by and we're only selecting the first one. Just remove the m.*.

Answer (score 0):

I've called the first table 'test'.

Firstly create a table that will hold all the identical combinations of ColA and ColB:

```
create temporary table tmpTable (ColA int, ColB int);
insert into tmpTable select ColA,ColB from test group by ColA, ColB;
```

Now, select the maximum id in the original table for each identical combination of ColA and ColB.  Put this into a new table (called idsToKeep because these are the rows we do not want to delete):

```
create temporary table idsToKeep (ID int);
insert into idsToKeep select (select max(ID) from test where test.ColA=tmpTable.ColA and test.ColB=tmpTable.ColB) from tmpTable;
```

Finally, delete all the entries from the original table that are not in the idsToKeep table:

```
delete from test where ID <> all (select ID from idsToKeep);
```

Comment: This approach guarantees that the row with the highest ID is not deleted.

Comment: That won't work if the row are not consecutive but the same ColA and ColB comes back in the sequence.